# Storing user files securely in Zend Framework 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework, encryption

I'm using Zend Framework 1.11 for building website. I want to implement functionality when user upload file and after can download it through API or web-interface. The thing is that I don't understand very well how to provide an acceptable level of security for the file storage.

I have the following structure of the project:

```
-My Project
    -application
    -data
    -docs
    -library
    -public
    -tests
```

Only folder "public" is publicly accessible. My idea was to save user files in folder "data". When user wants to download file he makes request to controller action, where I can check access rights. If user has access, php script will read corresponding file and send it to user.

My question is: if before saving user files I encrypt it (for example with AES-128 algorithm) will it somehow improve security of file storage? If yes, what is the best practice for keeping keys?

Comment: If you don't need to worry about storage then you can store these files in databas. That way they will be more secure.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

Create a folder **uploads** in My **Project/data**.

Add this lines to **index.php**

```
defined('UPLOADS_PATH')
    || define(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../data/uploads'));
```

Now you can use this path as a storage for new files uploaded.

*Check the permissions for write access for your webserver user!*

Now use this Path to **move_uploaded_file()** or add it as a **Rename** Filter to your **Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http**.

```
$adapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$adapter->addFilter('Rename',UPLOAD_PATH);
```

The uploaded files will get stored in **UPLOAD_PATH**.

If **$adapter->receive();** was called.

Now, you have stored the files in your **data/uploads** folder.

If you need some logic to store a file to a loggedin user or similar, you could just name the file with a leading or ending *user_id* like **4711-image.jpg**, where **4711** is the unique identifier.

If you need to handle multiple files, try creating a folder for the current user and name it with that unique identifier like **data/uploads/4711/image-1.jpg**.

These files will never be accessible as you already realized, only **public** is public accessible.

**But now, how should a user get these files?**

One idea is, generating some kind of **token** which gets stored in a database in relation to a user id or some other informations.

Or just use the folder and filename as unique identifier like **data/4711/image-1.jpg**.

Now create a Controller/Action that can read a query param (the token or the url_encoded filepath).

In your Action, get the file contents to a variable.

```
//get the file you want to present to the user
$userId = $this->_getParam('user_id',NULL); //eg. 4711
$fileId = $this->_getParam('file_id',NULL); //eg. image-1.jpg

//create the filepath
$filePath = $userId.'/'.$fileId;
//get the absolute system path
$fullPath = rtrim('/',UPLOAD_PATH).'/'.$filePath;

//check if file existing
if(@file_exists($fullPath)) {
    $fileContent = file_get_contents(fullPath); //content to var
    //create the file download
    $this->getResponse()
         ->setRawHeader('Content-type: application/octet-stream')
         ->setRawHeader('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($fullPath).'"')
         ->sendResponse();
    exit(0);
}
else {
    //nothing found (return 404)
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404)->sendResponse();
    exit(0);
}
```

Check these link:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.file.transfer.introduction.html

[How to download existing file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572894/how-to-download-existing-file-in-php)

[PHP - send file to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882472/php-send-file-to-user)

[Zend Framework: How to intentionally throw a 404 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188923/zend-framework-how-to-intentionally-throw-a-404-error)

Hope this helps!